# Integral with two measures with support shared

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, $\nu$ a measure on $ \mathcal{A} $ s.t. $\text{supp} (\nu) \subseteq \text{supp} (\mu) $ ($\text{supp} (\nu) = $ closure of $\{ E \in \mathcal{A} : \nu (E) > 0\}) $. If $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous is it true that $$\int_X f \ d \mu = \int_X f \ d \nu $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not, Take $\mu := \lambda$ and $\nu := 2\lambda$. (For any $\lambda \neq 0$).